# C#: Create a generic method that can return an enum as List<string>

Tags: c#, string, list, enums

How can I create a **generic** method that receives an enum type and return its values and names as a list of strings, so I could loop this list and for each iteration I'll be able to print each of the enum values. For example, consider the next pseudo:

```
enum MyEnum { A=5, B=6, C=8 }

List<string> createEnumStrings(AnyEnum(??))
{
  List<string> listResult;
  
  // ??
  // a code that will generate:
  // listResult[0] = "Value 5 Name A"
  // listResult[1] = "Value 6 Name B"
  // lsitResult[2] = "Value 8 Name C"

  return listResult;
}
```

Again, note that this method can get any type of an enum

Comment: Have you looked at [unconstrained melody](https://code.google.com/p/unconstrained-melody/)? It may be of use to you.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
public List<string> GetValues(Type enumType)
{
    if(!typeof(Enum).IsAssignableFrom(enumType))
        throw new ArgumentException("enumType should describe enum");

    var names = Enum.GetNames(enumType).Cast<object>();
    var values = Enum.GetValues(enumType).Cast<int>();

    return names.Zip(values, (name, value) => string.Format("Value {0} Name {1}", value, name))
                .ToList();     
}
```

now if you go with

```
GetValues(typeof(MyEnum)).ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
```

will print:

```
Value 5 Name A
Value 6 Name B
Value 8 Name C
```

Non-LINQ version:

```
public List<string> GetValues(Type enumType)
{   
    if(!typeof(Enum).IsAssignableFrom(enumType))
        throw new ArgumentException("enumType should describe enum");

    Array names = Enum.GetNames(enumType);
    Array values = Enum.GetValues(enumType);

    List<string> result = new List<string>(capacity:names.Length);

    for (int i = 0; i < names.Length; i++)
    {
        result.Add(string.Format("Value {0} Name {1}", 
                                (int)values.GetValue(i), names.GetValue(i)));
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: hmm.. can i do it without using Linq syntax?

Comment: @Popokoko May I ask what your aversion is to LINQ?

Comment: Thank you very much Ilya, both of ur solutions are using var variable and the @ notation, it bothers me a little and i wonder if it is a must? because that might be the reason i couldnt implement this myself ;(

Comment: I've removed `var` from Non-LINQ version. @ notation is used so that you can name your variable as `enum` (it's a reserved C# keyword, so you can't use it for a variable without @). Feel free to name the variable as you like

Comment: Enums can have duplicate names for values.  `Enum.GetNames` will return all of the names, i.e. it will return all of the choices for `enum MyEnum { Red = 0, Stop = 0, Yellow = 1, Green = 2, Go = 2 }`.

Comment: It's not that I dislike from LINQ, I'm just not experienced enough with that and currently interested in a more basic solution (though im aware of LINQ's capabilities!)

Comment: Okay Ilya i see, sorry about petty but this is obviously the solution I was looking for (and few more solutions from you :), thank you!

Comment: You should probably negate your if statement rather than wrap the entire function in it: `if(!typeof(Enum).IsAssignableFrom(enumType)) throw new ArgumentException("enumType should describe enum");`

Comment: @Cyborgx37 I agree in a sense, that it will reduce nested level of my main computation. On the other side - lots of conventions recommend to handle straight and happy cases first. It's really up to the developer to choose.

Comment: @IlyaIvanov - fair enough.

Comment: @Cyborgx37 thanks for a note thou, I thought for a moment and agreed to reduce nested level