# How do you create a generic function that will return all the names and values of a list of Enums?

Tags: c#, enums

I need to create an API that will return the names and values of various enums in a web application, so that I can use those names and values in select controls on the page. How do you put the list of enums into a form that can be serialized into json, with names and values for each enum?

Comment: I don't see how "I have enumerable of (key, value) pairs, how to return it as enumerable of (key, value) pairs instead of formatting it to string first" is a real question... Some edit to clarify what exactly you have trouble with (or think others will have trouble with as you already provided self-answer) would be nice.

Comment: Not a duplicate. This question is not about returning a list of strings.

The question is in the title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had never created a method where you could pass in a type and get out values, so using this answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/16639951/877129) to a slightly different question, I came up with the below answer that may help someone. Surely there's a better way, but this one is what I came up with.

Thanks to @Ilya Ivanov for the answer that got me there.

First, the EnumModel class:

```
public class EnumModel
{
  public int Value { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Next, the private function:

```
private List<EnumModel> GetValues(Type enumType)
{
  if (!typeof(Enum).IsAssignableFrom(enumType))
    throw new ArgumentException("enumType should describe enum");

  var values = Enum.GetValues(enumType).Cast<int>();

  var list = new List<EnumModel>();

  foreach(var value in values)
  {
    list.Add(new EnumModel()
    {
      Value = value,
      Name = Enum.GetName(enumType, value)
    });
  }

  return list;
}
```

And finally, calling that private function to get the response you need:

```
public List<EnumModel> SegmentTypeEnum
{
  get
  {
    return GetValues(typeof(SegmentType));
  }
  set { }
}
```

Comment: You don't need to pass a `Type` to the method.  Just use the generic type and call it like `GetValues<SegmentType>()`  and `Type enumType = typeof(EnumModel);`  Also I'd personally think that returning a list of the enum type would make more sense then the caller can get the numeric value or name as needed from that.

Comment: The method is to prevent repeating myself as much as possible, since I have several hundred enums to do this with. Returning the list of enum types... I'm going to have to think that one over to figure out how that would work...

Comment: @juharr, I've tried a few things, and don't see what you're talking about. If you've got a better way than I've done, I'd really like to see it. Please submit an answer for me. Thanks.

Comment: Actually you can just use the generic overload of [`Enum.GetValues`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.enum.getvalues?view=net-6.0#system-enum-getvalues-1) to get an array of all the enum values as the enum type  like this `var segments = Enum.GetValues<SegmentType>();`

Comment: And then to get the `int` and `string` values just `Enum.GetValues<SegmentType>().Select(x => new EnumModel { Value = (int)x, Name = x.ToString() }).ToList();`